# foreach loop ignoring array content

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop, foreach

I have a foreach loop that loops through an array, and spits out data in the form of a HTML table.

The basic flow is as follows

```
<?php foreach($credits as $credit) : ?>
    <?php if($credit['credit_type'] == "long") : ?>
            <?php if($credit['category_title'] != $oldvalue) : ?>
                <?php echo $oldvalue . " changed to ". $credit['category_title']; ?>
                <br /><?php echo $count; ?>
                <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $credit['category_position']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $credit['category_title']; ?></td>
                        <td><strong>Title</strong></td>
                        <td><strong>Role</strong></td>
                        <td><strong>Director</strong></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $credit['credit_position']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $credit['credit_heading']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $credit['credit_title']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $credit['credit_role']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $credit['credit_director']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <?php $oldvalue = $credit['category_title']; ?>
                <?php echo $count++; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

My problem is that in the first loop the credit type is commercial, and commercial has 2 entries however the loop only ever prints the first one, and not the second one, why is this? How can I resolve this?

The array I looping through looks like this,

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [credit_id] => 5
            [credit_heading] => Test Heading 4
            [credit_title] => Test Title 4
            [credit_role] => Test Role 4
            [credit_director] => Test Director 4
            [credit_type] => long
            [credit_position] => 1
            [date_created] => 2012-01-05 11:47:50
            [candidates_candidate_id] => 54
            [rel_id] => 
            [credits_candidate_id] => 
            [credits_credit_id] => 
            [category_title] => 
            [category_position] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [credit_id] => 2
            [credit_heading] => Test Heading 2
            [credit_title] => Test Title 2
            [credit_role] => Test Role 2
            [credit_director] => Test Director 2
            [credit_type] => long
            [credit_position] => 2
            [date_created] => 2012-01-04 07:46:15
            [candidates_candidate_id] => 54
            [rel_id] => 
            [credits_candidate_id] => 
            [credits_credit_id] => 
            [category_title] => 
            [category_position] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [credit_id] => 4
            [credit_heading] => Test Heading 3
            [credit_title] => Test Title 3
            [credit_role] => Test Role 3
            [credit_director] => Test Director 3
            [credit_type] => long
            [credit_position] => 1
            [date_created] => 2012-01-05 10:52:07
            [candidates_candidate_id] => 54
            [rel_id] => 2
            [credits_candidate_id] => 54
            [credits_credit_id] => 4
            [category_title] => Commercial
            [category_position] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [credit_id] => 6
            [credit_heading] => Test Heading 4
            [credit_title] => Test Title 4
            [credit_role] => Test Role 4
            [credit_director] => Test Director 4
            [credit_type] => long
            [credit_position] => 1
            [date_created] => 2012-01-05 11:48:31
            [candidates_candidate_id] => 54
            [rel_id] => 3
            [credits_candidate_id] => 54
            [credits_credit_id] => 6
            [category_title] => Commercial
            [category_position] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [credit_id] => 1
            [credit_heading] => Test Heading 1
            [credit_title] => Test Title 1
            [credit_role] => Test Role 1
            [credit_director] => Test Director 1
            [credit_type] => long
            [credit_position] => 1
            [date_created] => 2012-01-04 07:46:15
            [candidates_candidate_id] => 54
            [rel_id] => 1
            [credits_candidate_id] => 54
            [credits_credit_id] => 1
            [category_title] => Television
            [category_position] => 1
        )

)
```

and the final output looks likes this,

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>Commercial</td>
                    <td><strong>Title</strong></td>

                    <td><strong>Role</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Director</strong></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Test Heading 3</td>

                    <td>Test Title 3</td>
                    <td>Test Role 3</td>
                    <td>Test Director 3</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">

                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Television</td>
                    <td><strong>Title</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Role</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Director</strong></td>

                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Test Heading 1</td>
                    <td>Test Title 1</td>
                    <td>Test Role 1</td>

                    <td>Test Director 1</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Comment: I think it has something to do with `if($credit['category_title'] != $oldvalue)`.  You're skipping options with the same `category_title`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only outputting the table if the `category_title` is different :

`<?php if($credit['category_title'] != $oldvalue) : ?>`

Using the following worked :

```
    <?php foreach($credits as $credit) : ?>
        <?php if($credit['credit_type'] == "short") : ?> 
            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"> 
                <tr> 
                    <td><?php echo $credit['category_position']; ?></td> 
                    <td><?php echo $credit['category_title']; ?></td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr> 
                    <td><?php echo $credit['credit_heading']; ?></td> 
                    <td><a href="">Edit</a></td> 
                </tr> 
            </table> 
        <?php endif; ?> 
        <?php if($credit['credit_type'] == "long") : ?>
                <?php if($credit['category_title'] != $oldvalue) : ?>
                    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <?php endif; ?> 
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $credit['category_position']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $credit['category_title']; ?></td>
                            <td><strong>Title</strong></td>
                            <td><strong>Role</strong></td>
                            <td><strong>Director</strong></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $credit['credit_position']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $credit['credit_heading']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $credit['credit_title']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $credit['credit_role']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $credit['credit_director']; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                <?php $oldvalue = $credit['category_title']; ?>
                <?php if($credit['category_title'] != $oldvalue) : ?>
                    </table>
                <?php endif; ?> 

        <?php endif; ?> 
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: I am unsure as to how to implement your answer, I though I had done it correctly.

Comment: You didnt implement my answer - you implemented a different one - one that obviously doesnt work ...

Comment: You answer was extremely hard to follow, it bares no relevance to my example code

Comment: @sico87 really ?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8741760/foreach-loop-that-requires-to-stop-and-start-based-on-whats-in-a-array#8741822 I gave you the entire source

Comment: really I have used your code, but it adds a new table each time, I only want a new table when a new category title is found, other I just need to append a new row.

Comment: @sico87 well you should not have an idea of your problem - the IF statement prevents the code from running multiple times when the category_title changes - just moved the endif statement so that only the <table> is written on the change

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6430/discussion-between-sico87-and-manseuk)

Answer (score 0):

The error is:

```
<?php if($credit['category_title'] != $oldvalue) : ?>
// you goes farther only if category changed, so the second etry isn't posting.
```

Insert after:

```
<br /><?php echo $count; ?>
```

this:

```
<?php endif; ?>
```

end replace one endif in the end.